# Difference between setVisibility() and setAlpha()

Tags: android, android-view

What is the difference between setVisibility(View.GONE) and setAlpha(0f)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

setVisibility(View.GONE) will not only hide your view but it will also recycle the space occupied by this view. However setAlpha(0f) is equivalent to setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) that only hides the view and still takes the space in your layout.

Comment: Also note that `setAlpha()` is new to API Level 11, with an eye towards using it with hardware acceleration.

Comment: Also: You cannot interact with (i.e. touch) invisible views but you can touch transparent ones.

Comment: I know this is old but setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) is not equivalent to setAlpha(0f) when using ViewPropertyAnimator. (Which I think is a bug).

Comment: It seems like setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) is not the same as setAlpha(0), because when making a view invisible, then animating alpha property to 1 doesn't show the view.

Comment: setVisibility() and setAlpha() are different. Examples: visibility = INVISIBLE and alpha = 0 -> view is invisible, visibility = INVISIBLE and alpha = 1 -> view is invisible, visibility = VISIBLE and alpha =0 -> view is transparent (invisible), visibility = VISIBLE and alpha = 1 -> view is visble.

Answer (score 4):

`setVisiblity(View.GONE)` makes the View invisible:

> This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

`setAlpha(0)` just makes the View transparent, but it is still in the space and able to be interacted with.

Alpha docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(float)

Visibility docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be valuable to define that what is the difference between all **3** different cases below.

> Notice that also **setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)** and
>   **setAlpha(0f)** are different.

**setVisibility(View.GONE)**

Hides the view and removes the space that view occupied. Inactivates the ***OnClickListener*** that is bind to view.

**setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)**

Hides the view and keeps the space that view occupies. Inactivates the ***OnClickListener*** that is bind to view -> *if the occupied space is clicked, the event is NOT triggered*.

**setAlpha(0f)**

Hides the view and keeps the space that view occupies. Keeps the ***OnClickListener*** active that is bind to view -> *if the occupied space is clicked, the event is triggered*.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remove them and then show them again, it could be better to just set visibility to gone and then change back to visible again. setAlpha(0f) is equivalent to setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) that only hides the view

Answer (score 1):

`setVisibility(View.GONE)` makes your view invisible and not occupy place (which is different from `View.INVISIBLE`)

`setAlpha(0f)` makes your view become transparent but the view still occupy place and can receive some event such as click event

Answer (score 0):

setAlpha() - Sets the opacity of the view. This is a value from 0 to 1, where 0 means the view is completely transparent and 1 means the view is completely opaque like (0